# Convert UTF-8 to windows-1252 and write into csv in gwt 2.7.0 on tomcat v7

Tags: java, csv, gwt, encoding, utf-8

I am facing a problem with converting UTF-8 to windows-1252. I have to output symbols like ²,³,°. The customer wants to open the file in Excel without importing the file by double clicking.

System:
Frontend in gwt 2.7.0 with massive usage of gxt 3.1.4
Server on customer side is a tomcat v7
Testing is done on gwt build in server

The problem right now is, that the application supports Japanese symbols, which are displayed perfectly fine in UTF-8 but not in windows-1252. On the other hand, the ²,³,° symbols are displayed. The current solution is to collect the rows of the `csv` and put them in hidden fields inside a `FormPanel`. The `FormPanel` is then encoded and submitted.

```
public void postCsvForExcel( String url, Map<String, String> postData )
    {
        setSize( "0px", "0px" );
        setVisible( false );
        sinkEvents( Event.ONLOAD );

        setMethod( FormPanel.METHOD_POST );
        setEncoding( FormPanel.ENCODING_URLENCODED );

        VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
        add( panel );
        for( Entry<String, String> data : postData.entrySet() )
        {
            Hidden hiddenField = new Hidden( data.getKey(), data.getValue() );
            panel.add( hiddenField );
        }
        SubmitButton submit = new SubmitButton();
        panel.add( submit );
        setAction( url );
        FormElement.as( this.getElement() ).setAcceptCharset( "Cp1252" );
        RootPanel.get().add( this );
        submit();
    }
```

The Japanese characters are only displayed in the header. Facing this problem, I have extended the `HttpServlet` for POST operations to translate the `UTF-8` like following and removed the `FormElement.as( this.getElement() ).setAcceptCharset( "Cp1252" );` part from the method above.

```
public class ExporterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public ExporterServlet() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.service(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String filename = req.getParameter("filename");
        String content = req.getParameter("content");
        if(filename != null) {
            //resp.setContentType( getContentType( filename ) + "; charset=utf-8" );
            resp.setContentType( "text/csv" + "; charset=windows-1252" );
            resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"" );
            resp.setIntHeader("Expires", 0);
            resp.setContentLength(content.length());
            resp.setStatus(200);
            //resp.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
            resp.setCharacterEncoding( "windows-1252" );
            //byte[] destinationBytes = content.getBytes( "utf-8" );
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap( content.getBytes() );
            CharBuffer cb = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ).decode( bb );
            bb = Charset.forName( "windows-1252" ).encode( cb );
            resp.getOutputStream().write( bb.array() );
            resp.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems not to work. Am I missing sth.

Further information: I have observed one strange thing. The `doPost` method, although being called has no effect on the encoding of the file. I have tried to encode it in UTF-8 but the output was still windows-1252. When I removed the encoding of the `FormPanel` in the method before, the result was UTF-8.

Another question is, what is the correct encoding for windows-1252, I have tried both versions, cp1252 and windows-1252, I cant spot a difference in the result.

Comment: I think you have made it too complicated. I would just use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) API to generate `xls` with UTF-8 encoding. This would display all characters.

Comment: Sadly I am in no position to add new dependencies to this project. And it has to be csv, which the user opens in Excel with a double click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Japanese characters cant be displayed in cp1252. The instruction itself was not investigated properly. The customer doesn't know what cp1252 is capable of. Should have checked that before working on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code, and try it again:

```
filename = new String(filename.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1");
```